# Issues with Tag Overlap on Documentation

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation

How should tag overlap be handled?

For example, we have a [VBA tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) which covers everything related to the language, but also tags like [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) and [powerpoint-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint-vba). The distinction between those subcategories is essential, because many of the methods and properties, though similar, are substantially different, yet they still fall under the same syntax.

I believe that the tags should remain separate, but perhaps for "general topics" that are true for powerpoint-vba and excel-vba, but covered by the vba tag, should be linked to the sub-tags, rather than repeated for completeness. Should some hierarchy be established among tags to make this sort of sub-attribution easier?

Comment: This is also very relevant for languages like c and c++

Comment: Could you perhaps make this a feature request... I have noticed that there is a huge amount of unnecessary duplication going on between tags. particularly in languages that have other languages as a subset.

Comment: On the documentation beta a proposed the idea of Sub-Topics yet the issue for some reason was not given enough attention.

Comment: At least for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328751/what-should-we-do-about-overlapping-topics we agreed that we should find the common super-topic, and reference it where necessary. [like you suggest vba tag]. But perhaps it wouldn't be bad to have super-topics maybe merged somehow into the sub-topics (so that e.g. search on excel-vba will also give you general vba topics).