# Synonyms on documentation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

As a bit of a follow on from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328520/we-need-a-way-to-close-duplicate-doc-topic-requests/) could we perhaps implement some kind of synonym system the way we currently do for tag-wikis?

I'm already rejecting plenty of examples on the basis that they are not specific to a certain *version* or *subset* of another language and should in fact be part of a topic on the *main* language tag.

***e.g.***

---

[excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) **For Loops**                     *should move to >>>*        [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) **For Loops**
[excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) **Use Option Explicit**       *should move to >>>*       [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba) **Use Option Explicit**

---

I would suggest that this could be a way of dealing with 'generic' examples being added to topics in specific areas of a language where they actually apply to the language as a whole.

Comment: Why not allow subsets or 'child' tags? [excel-vba] would be a 'child' of [vba] and a user could 'drill-down' into the subject matter. The term 'synonym' implies a parallel importance but clearly [excel-vba] (and [word-vba], etc) is a subset of [vba]. TBH, I've thought SO on a whole could have benefited from something like this for a long time.

Comment: @Jeeped I actually would prefer something like that and it was my first line of thought - I only considered the synonym functionality because it already exists and assumed it could be implemented quicker, but sub-tags would absolutely be better

Comment: I proposed an idea for sub-topics in the beta (those question weren't moved over yet) so I would just expand on that and allow sub-tags in addition to sub-topics.

Comment: According to the creators though, documentation is meant to be a little disorganized just because it's going to rely on Google to direct users to the right place. (IMHO this isn't enough) There doesn't necessarily need to be a complete tag reorganization, just a better way to identify duplicate content for those writing documentation.

Comment: @4castle this is more than a little disorganised imho - it's going to be impossible to find what you're looking for reasonably and probably have contradictory examples in different tags

Comment: While I agree that there should be a better way to deal with overlap (I posted about [that](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328529/6408573) myself), I'm not sure its necessarily all that terrible to have duplicate topics in the sub tags.  Some users may not think to look into the general VBA tab when they are working with vba in excel specifically, and by nature of being written by different users, the examples themselves will be unique.  They may be quite similar across tags, but I don't think this is such a flaw that edits should be rejected

Comment: @RGA I get your point, but the other problem that brings is trying to 'police' each one of those examples in each tag to make sure they're consistent. If two examples are contradictory then that causes more work and confusion for everyone.